# Remove "Welcome to"... on Drupal's seven theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, title

I'm trying to remove the text "Welcome to" on the Drupal theme seven.
I want to keep my site name though as it stands it says "Welcome to Site Name" at the top left.

I just want it to say "Site Name".

Comment: you can post your answer as an answer to your own question and accept it to improve your accept rating and let people know that it is the correct answer

Comment: I can't do that unfortunately at my level :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to replace the variable `$title` with `$site_name`.

Answer (score 1):

this text will be removed automatically  once you create a new content (which promoted to front page)...
so don't worry about this.... another advanced way is to create your front page 
and insert the link of you page in "/admin/config/system/site-information" instead of "node" in the "Default front page" section

Comment: No I'm talking about the title, not the content.

Comment: all of this ==> 


Welcome to {site name}

No front page content has been created yet.

Add new content

==> will be removed after you create your first content